# Set contents of webview to html string (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

Is there any easy way to set the contents of a webview to an HTML string (without having to load a file)?

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:someURL];`

(Where `someURL` is used to resolve relative URLs in the HTML source.)

Answer (score 10):

```
[webView loadHTMLString:yourString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

You can use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]` if you desire to load stylesheets(css) or javascripts(js) files that are in your resources dir, if not, just use nil

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` on the mainFrame of the webView would do it.